# ASP.NET Core. Выход со всех устройств после смены пароля

Tags: c#, vue.js, asp.net-core

Всем привет. Есть вопрос. Как можно выйти со всех устройств после смены пароля?
Использую Vue.JS. Для регистрации использую JWT.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Два способа есть https://stackoverflow.com/q/45748732/5752652 первый попроще (уменьшать время действия токена), второй посложнее (кешировать ID токена и проверять кеш)

Comment: А стоит ли просто заново сгенерировать токен?

Comment: У вас задача на инвалидацию старого токена.

Comment: В таком случае, как я могу уменьшить время действия токена? Я не совсем понял, как это сделать.

Comment: Для этого у вас мало информации в вопросе. "Я использую JWT" - это может быть что угодно: от [кастомной реализации](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/23.7.php) до готовых либ. У вас что? Покажите ваш код создания токена для начала - тогда можно будет что-то советовать.

Comment: Готовые либы я не юзал.

Comment: Делал все практически как в этой статье. https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/23.7.php Только вместо JQuery - Vue.JS. И токен записывается в cookie.

Comment: Ну почитайте тогда написанный код на метаните, там ведь даже комментарии проставлены. Копипастить чужой код не понимая что он делает - путь к патчу Бармина.

Comment: Вы про время жизни токена, если не ошибаюсь?

Comment: Да, ведь вы именно про это спрашиваете. Или уже какой-то другой вопрос?

Comment: Я про комментарий в коде метанита `public const int LIFETIME = 1; // время жизни токена - 1 минута`

Comment: Так. А строку где эта константа используется вы читали? `expires: now.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(AuthOptions.LIFETIME)),`. Работали с TimeSpan, знаете как меньше минуты сделать?

Comment: Читал. Но она ведь добавляет время действие токена, так?

Comment: Добавляет к чему? Там написано "взять существующий токен и добавить ему ещё минуту"? Или там создаётся новый токен, ему устанавливается время "от сейчас до плюс минута"? И вы как раз хотели уменьшить этот интервал.

Comment: Возможно я нуб, либо я что-то не понял. В моем понимании это звучит так: "Там добавляется токен. Т.е. токен уже существует. Как я понял, нужно только изменить время действия токена. И вопрос, как к нему "подключиться"? Просто изменить..."

Comment: Я не могу понять, как получить созданный токен.

Comment: Метод public async Task Token() - это метод, когда приходит ваш vue.js и просит создать/выдать новый токен. Приход vue.js с токеном проверяется в коде asp.net core. Уменьшая время жизни токена вы (помимо увеличения нагрузки на метод выдачи токена) вы уменьшаете время жизни токена - это направление "а", "простое". Вы не можете уменьшить время жизни выданного токена, вы можете уменьшить время выдаваемых токенов - вот о чём речь.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91728/discussion-between-general2001-and-a-k).