# ASP.NET Core JWT. Сохранение данных пользователя

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, jwt

Всем привет. Много вопросов возникло с этой темой (JWT).
На данный момент у меня есть аутентификация с помощью JWT. При истечении времени жизни токена, пользователь выходит из системы (401).

Теперь вопрос. Как можно "оставить" пользователя в системе после истечения времени жизни токена? Без необходимости последующего входа. Т.к. остается проблема -  авторизироваться через определенное количество минут.

Буду рад слышать ваши ответы.

Comment: Никак. Вы хотите плохого. Делайте правильно: протух доступ - доступ закрыт. Вы квартиру запираете и уносите ключ с собой, а не оставляете торчать в замке "заходи кто хочешь, бери кто хочешь". Не хотел бы я пользоваться вашим приложением: уж сколько есть ошибок в ПО, но когда мечтают о заведомо дырявой модели с кучей угроз - это слишком. Сделайте токены бесконечной длины или даже вообще удалите все токены - пусть пользователи всегда остаются в системе и все с админскими правами.

Comment: Я понял, что это плохой вариант. Я и не говорю конкретно "сохранить"!

Comment: Тогда переформулируйте вопрос, нажав кнопку "править". Опишите проблему. Приведите код. Сформулируйте один вопрос, а не десять (один вопрос - одна тема).

Comment: Я имею ввиду, как можно создать, допустим, последующую авторизацию после истечения времени токена? При условии, что пользователь не будет повторно вводить данные.

Comment: Я ни разу не встречал приложения, где нужно было водить данные, к примеру, через каждые 5 минут.

Comment: Это проблема? Удлините время токена с 5 минут до 10 часов.

Comment: Допустим, прошло 10 часов... Нужно повторно вводить данные?

Comment: Допустим. Есть две модели. В строгой - да, будете вводить. В нестрогой - если за эти 10 часов были заходы на сервер, то при каждом заходе на сервер к времени жизни токена прибавляется 10 часов ([тынц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/962767/213987)). У вас приложение со строгой безопасностью?

Comment: Только прошу не закидывать тапками, но если я правильно понял, то есть и вариант со строгой безопасностью, где нужно повторно вводить данные. В таком случае, мне нужно прибавлять каждые 10 часов при входе в приложение. Как я могу это реализовать? Делал все как в этой статье https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/23.7.php

Comment: Это очень упрощённый пример на метаните: он хорош для старта, но то, что вы хотите уже выходит за рамки такого простого примера. Вы ищете функциональность, которую принято делать через refresh токены. Из того, что почитать рекомендую например https://www.blinkingcaret.com/2018/05/30/refresh-tokens-in-asp-net-core-web-api/

Answer (score 0):

сгенерируйте еще один токен который будет называться refreshToken, этот токен будет служить для обновления токена его нужно хранить в бд, срок refreshTokena  больше чем простой токен . На клиентской части если ответ приходит код 401 - рефрешнуть токен через refreshToken и  повторить запросы которые выдали 401.

Comment: Т.е., если выдается код 401, запрос на повторную авторизацию нужно отправлять с клиента? И по refreshToken найти пользователя. Я правильно понял?